# Are there cellular automata with "long range" rules?

Tags: reference-request, cellular-automata

Common cellular automata have rules that only check cells' immediate neighbours, in the current, immediate step. Have CA been explored that have rules that are "longer range" (spatially and temporally)? Could you recommend some resources I could look into to read more about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many such CA's that have ben explored. I recommend http://www.mirekw.com/ca/index.html. It has information about many different CA's, and allows you to download a program which can run all of those and many more. For further reading, I recommend the book, *A new kind of science*, by Stephen Wolfram.